# EditText is losing users' input when rotating android phone

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

- When a user types into the editText
  (landscape mode, or portrait) and
  rotates the phone the text is lost.

**QUESTION**

- How can I prevent the loss of the
  text ?

**underlying code:**

- onCreate()  -> 
  setContentView(myLayout)  ->  get
  references to UI widgets with
  findViewById()
- onConfigurationChanged()  ->  setContentView(myLayout)  ->  get references to UI widgets with findViewById()

my guess is that the setContentView() within onConfigurationChanged() causes the data loss.
What I believe I need to do is grab the data from the EditText before this happens. But how ?

Comment: solution: don't use setContentView() within onConfigurationChanged()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add

android:configChanges="orientation"

to your activity in the androidmanifest.xml. This will rotate the orientation but make no changes occur on orientation change.

```
<activity android:name=".activityname"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Comment: I was going to say "yeah that's what I have" and after I read up on onConfigurationChanged() I noticed that it's not necessary to use setContentView(R.layout.chat). I've been doing it wrong for 6 months !! <facepalm>

Comment: but I wonder what I would do when I want a different view for landscape mode. Possibly use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance() for data stored in the EditText

Comment: you can specify different xml files per orientation in their own folder with /res/layout-port/main.xml or /res/layout-land/main.xml

Comment: i dont think my two methods are compatible though. ive never tested it that way. if youd want to implement the above xml question with your original question, the solution would be saving data between the pre-orientation change activity's onDestroy() and the post-orientation change activity's onCreate(). I dont recall at the moment if variable instances are preserved across this timespan, if not then a solution with preferences or internal data storage may have to be coded

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but almost, that when the orientation changes the activity is completely recreated is it not? You would have to use bundle to save instance states and such, check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618897/when-i-change-the-orientation-from-portrait-to-landscape-my-calculated-result-is) about roughly the same topic and I'm sure you'll figure it out! Cheers!

Comment: I see that onSaveInstanceState() is the event I need, but unfortunately when the screen is rotated the resulting onConfigurationChanged() provides a Configuration type, instead of a Bundle. It would have been awesome if onConfigurationChanged() provided a Bundle instead  :-(