# loose date when change orientation

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when i change the orientation from portrait to landscape my calculated result is disappearing. how to resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618897/when-i-change-the-orientation-from-portrait-to-landscape-my-calculated-result-is)
>   [EditText is losing users' input when rotating android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657828/edittext-is-losing-users-input-when-rotating-android-phone)

In my application I have for example one EditText. In portrait mode I type the letters and when I rotate my device in I am seeing empty Edittext. Is there any way to do this? Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your data in

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyText", edtMyText.getText().toString());
}
```

and restore your data if any in `OnCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyText");
            edtMyText.setText(myString);
        }
    }
```

For clarity you may want to define

```
private static final String MYTEXT_SAVED_ITEM = "MyText";
```